# Terminal Server: how to map network drive for all users?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, terminal-server, net-use

I'm using Windows Server 2008 as a Terminal Server. How can I map a network drive for all users? Should I use a logon script and `net use` command? Where should I put it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Group Policy Preferences over either of the options you mentioned.  It's a much cleaner way to accomplish the task.  Here are some resources to help you with the specifics:

[Ask Directory Services Team Blogpost](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership.aspx)

[Group Policy Team Blogpost](http://blogs.technet.com/b/grouppolicy/archive/2009/02/11/gp-preferences-will-reduce-logon-scripts-mapping-drives.aspx)

Comment: I should add that I have admin rights for this server, but not for the domain...

Comment: Ah, this will not work for you since preference items are only available in domain-based GPOs.  Are you sure you can't convince someone with domain rights to craft that policy for you?  If not, you're stuck with a logon script and some "net use" commands.